# I think "/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build" points to incorrect folder

Tags: kernel, compiling, symbolic-link

I compile/create my own deb packages of kernel with:

```
make-kpkg --rootcmd fakeroot --initrd --append-to-version=$version --revision=1 kernel_image kernel_headers
```

But when I install both packages, in /lib/modules/(*name_kernel_compiled*) it creates two links, *sources and build*, pointing to folder with sources, from I've compiled.

*sources* link is correct but *build* should point to /usr/src/linux-(*version kernel*), don't you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is in `make-kpkg` documentation:

> You can look at other example in the examples directory: `/usr/share/kernel-package/examples/` to see if there are other example script you want to `cp` into `/etc/kernel` -- and you can create your own scripts.

---

> For example, if you use `linux-headers-*` packages to compile third party modules so that you do not have to keep the sources directory around, you might be interested in:

```
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/link
/etc/kernel/header_postrm.d/link
/etc/kernel/header_prerm.d/link
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/force-build-link
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/force-build-link
```

> These scripts will try to make sure that the symlink `/lib/modules/$VERSION/build` is sane -- that is points to the header packages whether you install the image packages first, or the header packages first -- and takes care of cleanup when either of the packages are installed.

Answer (score 4):

The `/lib/modules/<version>/build` symlink should point to the build directory - ie, where the object files were placed during the kernel build. In your case, your source dir is the same as your build dir, so both symlinks will point to the same directory.