# How could I write a kernel module to extend the radiotap fields?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, kernel

According to the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man9/ieee80211_radiotap.9freebsd.html), Ubuntu only supports the following fields:

IEEE80211_RADIOTAP_TSFT

IEEE80211_RADIOTAP_FLAGS

IEEE80211_RADIOTAP_RATE

IEEE80211_RADIOTAP_CHANNEL

IEEE80211_RADIOTAP_DBM_ANTSIGNAL

IEEE80211_RADIOTAP_DBM_ANTNOISE

IEEE80211_RADIOTAP_DBM_TX_POWER

IEEE80211_RADIOTAP_ANTENNA

IEEE80211_RADIOTAP_DB_ANTSIGNAL

IEEE80211_RADIOTAP_DB_ANTNOISE

IEEE80211_RADIOTAP_XCHANNEL

I want to write a kernel module that will supply the [VHT](https://www.radiotap.org/fields/VHT.html) and [MCS](https://www.radiotap.org/fields/MCS.html) fields if the driver can provide them.

I've written kernel modules before, but it's been a while, and I'm not sure exactly where to start for network stuff. I would appreciate a general outline if anyone is able to give it.

Comment: I regret that version 14.04 has reached end of life https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases and https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic states in part: "You should avoid asking questions regarding...Support for versions for Ubuntu releases past their Support or "End of Life" (EOL) — unless the question is asking how to upgrade to a supported release." However https://ubuntuforums.org/ and http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/ may be helpful as might https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+questions?field.search_text=14.04+kernel

Comment: Also https://www.linuxquestions.org/ may be helpful.

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu 14.04 ESM (supported by Canonical) you can use your Ubuntu Advantage support options (*which isn't here*).

Comment: @K7AAY I edited my question. Ubuntu 18.04 has the same issue, so I expect that the general starting point would probably be the same for me. Even if it's not, it would still be helpful.

Comment: Anyway this question is too broad for AU.

Comment: Over my (wooden) head, but these may be helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111417/unable-to-build-simple-hello-world-kernel-module https://askubuntu.com/questions/184593/reverse-engineer-driver-for-multi-colored-backlit-keyboard-on-clevo-laptops/274600#274600 https://askubuntu.com/questions/57119/building-a-new-vanilla-kernel-some-confusion-with-the-produced-debs